# How to save list into csv file using python

Tags: python-3.x

Here I have a list value  with date and x . Here I want to save this list value in new csv file with two columns date and x.

I tried many methods and it gave me new error.

```
x_new_value = [{'date':current_time, 'x':current_x }]

some code is running for get the new x value
after that:
x_new_value.append({'date':next_record_time, 'x':new_x})
for i in x_new_value:
print(i['date'], "\t\t", i['x'])

the output :
```

```html
2018-06-08 15:00:00    0.02
2018-06-08 16:00:00    0.0195
2018-06-08 17:00:00    0.018
2018-06-08 18:00:00    0.016
2018-06-08 19:00:00    0.013
```

Then I want to write this data in csv file :
I tried this code:

```
x_new_value.to_csv('Call.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

```html
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-e81fa450a0b0> in <module>()
      1 import csv
----> 2 x_new_value.to_csv('Call.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: try the csv package https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: @abhilb sure, thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(x_new_value).to_csv('Call.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. This is the answer I was looking forward.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to answers already provided, you can simply do the usual write to a file:

```
import datetime
f = open("file.csv", "a")
record_time = datetime.datetime.now()
current_x = 0
for i in range(0, 20):
    record_time += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    current_x+= 1
    f.write(record_time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y - %H:%M:%S") + "," + str(current_x)+"\n")

f.close()
```

If you do so, make sure you've set your date format correctly, and protect delimiters properly.